# How to sort solr search results by most matching keywords?

Tags: commerce, hooks, search

I'm using apachesolr in drupal commerce site. If user searches for a book spring, it returns all results which contain the word spring. But If I search for Spring Sofia or Spring by sofia (sofia is author name), It should return the book Spring by Sofia first and then show the rest of the results. Right now it's shown somewhere in the middle.

How can I make it to sort results keeping in view all the keywords?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Try to increase the weightage of the field author. Increase the word limit for indexing and then sort by relevancy.

Comment: Apache solr supports boost query to improve the search results / returns more related documents indexed. 
Try With query boost query :
?q=Spring by Sofia&fq=contenttype&fq=Spring^10 +Sofia^2

Comment: Thank you @BalaVaradarajan, your comment gave me a hint to know about boost queries etc (+1 for it). I've tried it using different combinations, m waiting for client to approve it.                 @ Gokul I've not just author for book, I've ISBN, product sku, series, author, publisher. The user can search by one or more of these options.